# How to parameterise variable length of Strings?

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I am writing a query where 'batch_name' is the parameter, some times I get only one batch name and sometime I get 2 or more batch names. How can I handle this in Oracle BI Publisher query,

Here is my query,

`Select * from pay_batch_headers pbh Where UPPER(pbh.batch_name)      =  UPPER(:p_batch_name)`

Now this query will handle for only one batch name, I want it to handle multiple batch names.

something like `Where UPPER(pbh.batch_name) IN ('Batch1','Batch2','Batch3')`
But problem to use IN clause is I cant predict number of batches I have to query. Can any one help me in this please.

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? They're different things.

Comment: @RichBenner Its Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two choices.  One is to munge the variables together into a string and use some method, such as `regexp_like()`:

```
where regexp_like(upper(pbh.batch_name), ??)
```

The parameter string should look like:  `'^abc|def|ghi|jkl$'`.  You can make it as long as you like.

Another method is to use `execute immediate`.  Dump the values into a SQL query as a string, using `IN`.  The advantage of this method is that it can more easily use indexes

Comment: I was looking at 1st solution , here where can I Pass parameter `:p_batch_name`. The query will look like `Select * from pay_batch_headers pbh 
Where regexp_like(upper(pbh.batch_name), ??);`

Comment: Thank you it worked, i replaced ?? to my parameter :p_batch_name